# AngularJS smart-table not sorting

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Using AJAX data, so I declare thusly:

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="eventStationsAnalyticData"  
        class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th st-sort="getters.station_id">Station #</th>
           <th st-sort="station_name">Station name</th>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <th colspan="5"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="Global search ..." type="text"/></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
           <td>{{row.station_id}}</td>
           <td>{{row.station_name}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

There are no sort arrows visible (the CSS **is** included), and a breakpoint on the sort function is not being hit.

I believe that I have copied from the example & edited, but ...

Who can help?

---

[Update] Search is also not working. And, even if I remove the search, the sort still doesn't work.

Note to self, it seems to work in [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsSXGN?p=preview), which you forked at the office. Try to figure out the difference to your actual code when you get home.

It is could possibly be something not visible here, such as a missing file; but, don't rule anyhing out.